# webpack using font awesome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

in my react app I want to use fontawesome css files with webpack and the css loaders. my configuration looks like this:

webpack config

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ["es2015", { modules: false }],
            "stage-2",
            "react"
          ],
          plugins: [
            "transform-node-env-inline"
          ],
          env: {
            development: {
              plugins: ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff2?|otf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
            loaders: ['file']
        },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: "[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:8]"
            }
          },
          "postcss-loader" // has separate config, see postcss.config.js nearby
        ]
      },
    ]
```

in index.js I have this:

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

and in the render method i have this:

```
<li><NavLink to="/dashboard" className="fa fa-bars" activeClassName="activeSidebar"
                                         aria-hidden="true"></NavLink></li>
```

There are noe errors, but also no icons displayed ... whats my mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me is to add the css files in my www/index.html

then I can use the css like this:

```
<div className={`row`}>
```

Same with bootstrap and fontawesome

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a name argument to the loader that handles the font files.

eg:

```
...
{
 test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff2?|otf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
 loader: 'file-loader?name=./[name].[hash].[ext]'
},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Webpack 2, [you should always add the `-loader` suffix after each loader's name.](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed) Here's my portion of code that works correctly in my webpack.config.js:

```
        {
            test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            use:[{
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options:{
                    limit: 100000,
                    name: 'assets/resources/[name].[ext]'
                }
            }]
        }
```

I'm using `url-loader`, but in this case it should work with `file-loader` too.

Answer (score 1):

well, in my case, I shall add a small pattern after the extension for the `url-loader` and some `include` / `exclude` instructions.

This is because we want to have different *tools* for our css and imported ones.

The pattern added in `url-loader` is to handle import from `font-awesome.css` because they look like : `src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');`

Here is the extract of my `webpack.config.js` file :

```
  {
    test: /\.css/,
    loaders: [
      'style-loader',
      `css-loader?${JSON.stringify({
        sourceMap: isDebug,
        // CSS Modules https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: isDebug ? '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]' : '[hash:base64:4]',
        // CSS Nano http://cssnano.co/options/
        minimize: !isDebug,
        camelCase: 'dashes',
      })}`,
      'postcss-loader',
    ],
    exclude: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/font-awesome'),
    ],
  },

// ...
  {
    test: /\.css/,
    loaders: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
    ],
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/font-awesome'),
    ],
  },
 // ...

{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff|woff2)(\?.*$|$)/,
  loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
},
```